# Creating WCF Data Service operation with in-memory objects

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I am trying to create a WCF DataService using in-memory object graph. This means that the backend is not an Entity Framework store, but a bunch of objects that reside in memory.

I am trying to create a service operation called **GetUsersByName** that has a single parameter for name and returns the matching users as an IQueryable collection.

I followed the documentation and added the access rules for this operation

```
config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("GetUsersByName", ServiceOperationRights.All);
```

But when the **SetServiceOperationAccessRule** method is called I receive an exception on the client:

```
System.AggregateException was unhandled.
```

Here is the full code for my console application

```
    using System;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceModel.Web;
    using System.ServiceModel.Description;
    using System.Data.Services;
    using System.Data.Services.Common;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Net;
    using System.IO; 

    namespace WCF_OData
    {

        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string serviceAddress = "http://localhost:8080";
                Uri[] uriArray = { new Uri(serviceAddress) };
                Type serviceType = typeof(UserDataService);

                using (var host = new DataServiceHost(serviceType, uriArray)) {
                    host.Open();

                    var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(serviceAddress) };
                    Console.WriteLine("Client received: {0}", client.GetStringAsync("Users?$format=json").Result);

                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8080");
                    request.Method = "GET";
                    request.Accept = @"application/json";

                    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
                        Console.WriteLine(response.ContentType);
                        Console.WriteLine((new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd());
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop service");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }

            }
        }

        [EnableJsonSupport]
        [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]   
        public class UserDataService : DataService<UserService> {
            public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
            {
                config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Users", EntitySetRights.All);
                config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("GetUsersByName", ServiceOperationRights.All);

                config.UseVerboseErrors = true;

                config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
            }

        }

        public class UserService
        {
            private List<User> _List = new List<User>();

            public UserService()
            {
                _List.Add(new User() { ID = 1, UserName = "John Doe" });
                _List.Add(new User() { ID = 2, UserName = "Jane Doe" });
            }

            public IQueryable<User> Users
            {
                get
                {
                    HttpContext x = HttpContext.Current;
                    return _List.AsQueryable<User>();
                }
            }

            [OperationContract]
            [WebGet(UriTemplate="GetUsersByName")]
            public IQueryable<User> GetUsersByName(string name)
            {
                return new List<User>().AsQueryable(); 
            }
        }

        [DataServiceKey("ID")]
        public class User
        {
            public int ID { get; set; } 
            public string UserName { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why are your service and console app in the same place? How are you hosting the service? Have you tried calling the service op from a browser? What does the stack trace say?

Comment: I want this to be a self hosted service. I am hosting the service in a Console project and then calling the service from the same app. The calls are there in the console just for easier testing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a few things going on here, so this may take a couple of iterations to work through. The first problem that should be fixed is the service operation. Service operations need to be declared on the class that inherits from DataService: ["Service operations are methods added to the data service class that derives from DataService"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668788.aspx). Here's a sample:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Services;
using System.Data.Services.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace Scratch.Web
{
    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class ScratchService : DataService<ScratchEntityFrameworkContext>
    {
        static ScratchService()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new ScratchEntityFrameworkContextInitializer());
        }

        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
        }

        [WebGet]
        public IQueryable<Product> FuzzySearch(string idStartsWith)
        {
            var context = new ScratchEntityFrameworkContext();
            return context.Products.ToList().Where(p => p.ID.ToString().StartsWith(idStartsWith)).AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

You should then be able to call your service operation from a browser, with a URL format similar to the following: `http://localhost:59803/ScratchService.svc/FuzzySearch()?idStartsWith='1'`

Can we start by trying to get this functional in a browser and then see whether the AggregateException still happens?

Comment: it works that way. The only problem I have now is that I cannot automagically create the proxy in my clients (by adding the web reference) that would include the operations as well. My understanding that this is not implemented.

Comment: That's correct, I believe - no code gen for service ops (yet :)).